# Hide automatically the keyboard in preview mode

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When you edit a question, you have the option to see the update in preview screen. While this mode is displayed, the keyboard (`SoftKeyboard`) should disappear automatically. Because this makes no sense to let the keyboard opened whereas you can't edit the text.

Here's a screenshot about this feature:

[image: Screenshot preview mode - softkeyboard]

*To reproduce:*
    *1. Edit a question -> Preview mode (in portrait), it takes **half of the screen***
    *2. Edit a question -> Preview mode (in portrait) -> Then, change orientation (in landscape)*